# show formatted xml in textbox

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I've been searching for a way to show formatted xml in a textbox, everything I've found so far points towards reading in xml from a file and formatting that, however I want to show xml which is held in a database field.

The idea is that a user will have records returned to a gridview, the gridview will show everything apart from the xml message due to its size. They can then select the record and show the xml on a pop-up form.

I have the xml passed to the pop-up form, just not sure how to handle it.
Any ideas welcome.

Comment: Is this on a web site or a windows application?

Comment: tell me what step you are right now... are you able to GET the XML from the DB? if yes, then i would assume that you already have the string ready to be written in that UI Control that you have? in this case, a _pop-up_?

Comment: correct, have the xml and just looking for the best way to write it to the pop-up

Comment: sorry, its a web site

Comment: You should take a look at http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/, which allows you to display code with syntax hightligting. Simply wraps the **encoded** xml string into a `<pre class="brush: xml">` tag, and let the plugin do its jobs

Answer (score 37):

Got round it by using

```
xmlOut = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(txtXml).ToString();
```