# Displaying string that is XML form as XML in Web Forms(PrintBox.Text)

Tags: c#, xml, string, webforms

I have an MemoryStream that has xml info that is being translated to a string

```
        myString= Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Position);

        //Then I am setting that to the PrintBox
        PrintBox1.Text = myString;
        PrintBox1.DataBind();
```

The result is an ugly string that has xml formatting. I want to display it as an xml or at least keep the indentation like the xml.

Comment: check this url: [show formatted xml in textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894661/show-formatted-xml-in-textbox)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [show formatted xml in textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894661/show-formatted-xml-in-textbox)

Comment: As an aside, you're using `Encoding.ASCII`, are you certain your XML will never contain non-ASCII characters?  It's usually safer with no loss of functionality to use `Encoding.UTF8`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is quick solution (`using` lines are omitted):

```
myString= Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Position);
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(myString);
xmlDoc.Save(sw);
String formattedXml = sw.ToString();
PrintBox1.Text = formattedXml;
PrintBox1.DataBind();
```